# Create string literal type that excludes union?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a type that will allow any string excluding an existing union of string literals?

For example:

```
export type TExcludeThese = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';

const myVar = 'four'; // This can be anything string that isn't in TExcludeThese
```

Comment: There's no easy way to do this; technically it is possible by writing a huge union of string interpolation types like ``'' | `${NotOorT}${string}` | `o${NotNE}` | `t${NotWOorHREE}` `` where `NotOorT`, `NotNE` and `NotWOorHREE` are defined similarly as unions of what *is* allowed. But don't do that, it's horrible. What's the reason that you want to exclude some specific string values from the type? Maybe there is a nicer solution which involves defining those three as some non-string type, like an enum, so that there's no overlap between your type and `string`.

Comment: @kaya3, we started having naming collisions between teams from things in our component library on element IDs. So we're trying to prevent certain words from being able to be passed to a component as an ID

Comment: `type Ex<T extends string, Block> = T extends Block ? never : T;` gets close, but usage is clunky: `const myVar: Ex<"three", TExcludeThese> = "three";` [Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N53y0W)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that might be as close as I get, thanks

Comment: If the problem is to prevent naming collisions, would requiring each team to use a distinct prefix help? For example team 1's names can be of type `` `foo${string}` `` and team 2's names can be of type `` `bar${string}` ``, and so on.

Comment: You could also consider using unique symbol types, i.e. `const foo = Symbol();`, then `obj[foo]` can never collide with any property defined by another team that has no access to `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by kaya3 et. al. currently typescript does not support this feature directly, therefore you can try with tagged type alternatively, if the idea is simply to avoid collision, e.g.

```
// team-a.ts
export type One = 'one' & { readonly __type: unique symbol };
export type Two = 'two' & { readonly __type: unique symbol };
export type Three = 'three' & { readonly __type: unique symbol };

// team-b.ts
export type One = 'one' & { readonly __type: unique symbol };
export type Two = 'two' & { readonly __type: unique symbol };
export type Three = 'three' & { readonly __type: unique symbol };

// app.ts
import {One as OneA} from './a';
import {One as OneB} from './b';
let teamA = {
    id: 'one' as OneA
}
let teamB = {
    id: 'one' as OneB
}
teamA = teamB // error
```

Downside is it is a bit verbose, and it might not work well with 3rd party typings.